# Rails - Custom html into simple_form label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form

I'm trying to customize the output of a simple_form association, basically I need to display a checkbox label on two lines. My idea was adding a "br" tag into the "label", but unfortunately it gets escaped so it display actually "br" instead of going to a new line

I use a lambda for customizing the label output

```
<%= f.association :item, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => current_user.items, :label => false, :label_method => lambda { |item| "#{item.city.capitalize},<br> #{item.address}" }%>
```

this produces an escaped br into the label string, how could I display the label on two lines?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

call `html_safe` method on the string you want not to be escaped.

```
<%= f.association :item, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => current_user.items, :label => false, :label_method => lambda { |item| "#{item.city.capitalize},<br> #{item.address}".html_safe }%>
```

Comment: Seems it's vulnerable to an XSS attack. You should have forced escaping on user input, i.e.: `"#{h item.city.capitalize},<br> #{h item.address}".html_safe`

Comment: This comment adds nothing useful, but thank you - a simple solution to an aggravating problem.

Answer (score 15):

For those of you looking to have custom html in  elements as the title of the OP's question suggests, you can do this:

```
= f.input(:Foo, label: "Foo <span>(Blah helper text blah)</span>".html_safe)
```

Answer (score 2):

Does `html_safe` help?

```
<%= f.association(....).html_safe %>
```

if not, then post an example app on github showcasing this issue, so we can debug it