# Two Association Label Elements in Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, simple-form

How can I add two label elements when choosing association in Simple Form on Ruby on Rails?

Sample: `@user.name = "Barack"` and
`@user.last_name = "Obama"`

Here is my code:

```
<%= f.association :persona, :collection => Persona.order(:name), 
:prompt => 'Choose a person' %>
```

It displays only Barack but I need it to display not only `name` but also `last_name` when choosing from list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= f.association :persona, :collection => Persona.order(:name), :label_method => lambda { |persona| "#{persona.name} #{persona.last_name}" }, :prompt => 'Choose a person'%>
```

[Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671310/rails-custom-html-into-simple-form-label) - you need a complex label_method.