# Simple Form: how to add a span tag around the text value for each checkbox in a collection association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using the Materialize admin template and I need to correctly format the checkboxes using Simple Form, adding a span tag around the text value for each checkbox.

I've tried some wrapper options that Simple Form provides and also tried to create my own custom input, but I'm not getting the expected results.

This is the current code in my view, although I've already tried many different things.

```
<%= f.association :market_segments,
                  required: true,
                  label: false,
                  as: :check_boxes %>
```

I need the HTML in each checkbox to be like this:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span>Restaurant</span>
</label>
```

but I keep getting this:

```
<span class="checkbox">
  <label for="market_segment_ids_1">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Restaurant
  </label>
</span>
```

Do I really need to create a custom input to achieve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help:

```
<%= f.association :market_segments, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false, :label_method => lambda { |market_segment| "<span>#{market_segment.name}</span>".html_safe }%>
```

The above code is for your understanding so that you can achieve your goal.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671310/rails-custom-html-into-simple-form-label)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: I did, but since I'm new here and have less than 15 reputation, apparently the upvote isn't displayed. =/