# simple_form - change association legend text

Tags: simple-form

If I have a simple_form association (`as: :checkboxes`), how can I customize the text that appears inside the `legend` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered how, with some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24861083/199712).

```
  <%= f.association :inventory_sublocations,
    collection: location.inventory_sublocations,
    label: 'my custom label', # "my custom label" will appear inside the legend tag
    as: :check_boxes %>
```